# Why does a recursive cte not return duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I happened to encounter the following sql statement

```
DECLARE @SDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TDate DATETIME
SET @SDate = '2011-9-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @TDate = '2011-10-01 00:00:00.000'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @SDate Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date + 1 FROM CTE WHERE Date + 1 <= @TDate
)
SELECT Date FROM CTE
```

To my knowledge, this statement should return quite a lot of duplicates as each iteration in the recursion increments the entire column by 1 and the result should be a UNION ALL of all the intermediate tables.

However to my surprise the resulting table contains no duplicates, just all the distinct dates from 2011-9-01 to 2011-10-01. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think of recursive CTEs as actually being "recursive".  They are inductive.

The anchor portion of the CTE runs.  Then the "recursive" part keeps adding rows -- based on the most recently added rows.  So, the first iteration adds the first date.  The second iteration takes the just-added date and adds one to it.

The third iteration only considers the **second** (last) date, not both.

The terminology is not great, but they do not generate duplicates by reprocessing a given row more than once.

Answer (score -1):

Did you test this?

```
DECLARE @SDate DATETIME
SET @SDate = '2011-9-01 00:00:00.000'
select @SDate; 
select @SDate + 1;
```