# Join tables by date ON less than or equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to calculate users' profits based on their daily balance.

### Sample data per user: (vTnxDaily)

| DateOfDay | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-20 | $250 |
| 2024-02-12 | $80 |
| 2024-02-01 | $420 |

### Expected output:

| DateOfDay | Profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-29 | $250 / 3 |
| 2024-02-28 | $250 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-20 | $250 / 3 |
| 2024-02-19 | $80 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-12 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-11 | $420 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-01 | $420 / 3 |

**Since users do not have daily transactions, gaps must be filled with the latest available data. For instance, if a user only has transactions on Feb 1 and Feb 20, then all days below 20 are calculated based on the last data, which is Feb 1. And for days above 20, the last date used is Feb 20.**

### Try to calculate all days

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027684/get-all-dates-of-given-month-and-year-in-sql-server), all days in a month are produced. When I try to join, I cannot eliminate (get rid of) either duplicate or null values.

#### Try 1

```sql
-- produce all days
Declare @year int = 2024, @month int = 2;
WITH numbers
as
(
    Select 1 as value
    UNion ALL
    Select value + 1 from numbers
    where value + 1 <= Day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
)
SELECT datefromparts(@year,@month,numbers.value) Datum 
into #t
FROM numbers

-- join by the daily view
select t.Datum,v.*
from #t t left join
    vTnxDaily v on t.Datum=v.DateOfDay and v.UserId='user id'

drop table #t
```

##### Wrong result (1)

It produces null rows for missed days

| DateOfDay | Profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-29 | null |
| 2024-02-28 | null |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-20 | $250 / 3 |
| 2024-02-19 | null |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-12 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-11 | null |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-01 | $420 / 3 |

#### Try 2

To remove null values, I manipulated the join and used `<=` but it raises another problem: duplicate rows.

```sql
select t.Datum,v.*
from #t t left join
    vTnxDaily v on t.Datum>=v.DateOfDay and v.UserId='user id'
```

##### Wrong result (2)

It produces duplicate (or more) rows for higher days

| DateOfDay | Profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-29 | $250 / 3 |
| 2024-02-29 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-29 | $420 / 3 |
| 2024-02-28 | $250 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-20 | $250 / 3 |
| 2024-02-20 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-20 | $420 / 3 |
| 2024-02-19 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-19 | $420 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-12 | $80 / 3 |
| 2024-02-12 | $420 / 3 |
| 2024-02-11 | $420 / 3 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-02-01 | $420 / 3 |

#### Finally

The second query produces the correct value, but duplicate rows must be removed.
I also have tried to use `UNION` and some other options, but I failed.

#### Reproduce

MS SQL Server 2019,
[Live Sample on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8fhnLQNb)

Comment: Have you tried to `GROUP BY Datum` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```sql
select t.Datum, SUM(v.amount), COUNT(v.id)
from #t t left join
    vTnxDaily v on t.Datum>=v.DateOfDay and v.UserId='user id'
    GROUP BY t.Datum
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: So syntax specific for 2022 or acceptable or not..?

Comment: I use MSSQL 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* you are on the latest version of SQL Server (2022 at time of writing), you can use `GENERATE_SERIES` to get all the dates you need (an rCTE is not the most performant way), and then use the `IGNORE NULLS` feature added to functions like `LAST_VALUE` to get the last non-`NULL` value:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'2024-02-20'), CONVERT(decimal(18,4),250)),
            (CONVERT(date,'2024-02-12'), CONVERT(decimal(18,4),80)),
            (CONVERT(date,'2024-02-01'), CONVERT(decimal(18,4),420)))V(DateOfDay,Balance);

GO
WITH DateBoundaries AS (
    SELECT MIN(DateOfDay) AS StartDate,
           EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS EndDate
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, GS.value,DB.StartDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM DateBoundaries DB
         CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0,DATEDIFF(DAY,DB.StartDate,DB.EndDate)) GS)
SELECT D.CalendarDate,
       LAST_VALUE(YT.Balance) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY D.CalendarDate) AS Profit
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON D.CalendarDate = YT.DateOfDay
ORDER BY D.CalendarDate DESC;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

If you aren't on SQL Server 2022+, you'll need to be more "imaginative". I use a Tally here to create the dates instead, (which again is more performant than an rCTE). Then an `APPLY` to get the "latest" balance for said date:

```sql
WITH DateBoundaries AS (
    SELECT MIN(DateOfDay) AS StartDate,
           EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AS EndDate
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,DB.StartDate,DB.EndDate) FROM DateBoundaries DB)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM N N1, N N2,N N3), --UP to 1,000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I,DB.StartDate) AS CalendarDate
    FROM DateBoundaries DB
         CROSS JOIN Tally T)
SELECT D.CalendarDate,
       B.Balance AS Profit
FROM Dates D
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) YT.Balance
                  FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                  WHERE YT.DateOfDay <= D.CalendarDate
                  ORDER BY YT.DateOfDay DESC) B
ORDER BY D.CalendarDate DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jjjwkjCC)